# Gmail Inbox Read Only

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I am having trouble trying to get my IMAP STORE command to work with Gmail. From googling it seems several other people have had this problem, some seem to have found a fix and never said what it was and some just stopped. I am not sure how to fix it.

When I connect to Gmail I am given only Read Only access to the mailbox

```
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] C: '0003 EXAMINE INBOX'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* FLAGS (\\Answered \\Flagged \\Draft \\Deleted \\Seen)'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] UIDs valid.'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* 22 EXISTS'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* 0 RECENT'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '* OK [UIDNEXT 110] Predicted next UID.'
2013-03-05 01:22:47-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '0003 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)'
```

So when I select the Inbox it is Read Only

I then later on try and delete a message and I get this error

```
2013-03-05 01:43:04-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] C: '000E STORE 2 FLAGS.SILENT (\\Deleted)'
2013-03-05 01:43:04-0500 [IMAP4Client (TLSMemoryBIOProtocol),client] S: '000E NO STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)'
```

Twisted report this error, STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder, which is expected as I was only given read only access. How do I gain READ-WRITE access;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.mail.imap4.IMAP4Exception: STORE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)
```

RFC Information
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.1

```
  If the client is permitted to modify the mailbox, the server
  SHOULD prefix the text of the tagged OK response with the
  "[READ-WRITE]" response code.

  If the client is not permitted to modify the mailbox but is
  permitted read access, the mailbox is selected as read-only, and
  the server MUST prefix the text of the tagged OK response to
  SELECT with the "[READ-ONLY]" response code.  Read-only access
  through SELECT differs from the EXAMINE command in that certain
  read-only mailboxes MAY permit the change of permanent state on a
  per-user (as opposed to global) basis.  Netnews messages marked in
  a server-based .newsrc file are an example of such per-user
  permanent state that can be modified with read-only mailboxes.
```

I know Gmail's IMAP implementation is broken ( http://memegenerator.net/instance/35708036 )
but as far as I can tell Mail.app, Thunderbird, etc are able to delete messages so what am I missing to get READ-WRITE access....

Deletion Code

```
def delete_data(self, data_hash):
    if not self.hash_database.hash_in_list(data_hash):
        print "Data hash isn't uploaded yet"
        raise IOError("No such data hash uploaded")

    else:
        # delete it to prevent anyone from trying to download it while it is being deleted
        self.hash_database.delete_hash(data_hash)
        d = self.imap_connection.search("SUBJECT", "\"EMS Data ID: %s\"" % data_hash, uid = False)
        d.addCallback(self.delete_message)
        d.addErrback(self.deletion_error, data_hash)
        return d

def deletion_error(self, error, data_hash):
    print "Couldn't delete message hash %s" % data_hash
    print "========Deletion Error========"
    log.err(error)
    # restore hash to database
    self.hash_database.add_hash(data_hash)
    
    raise IOError("Couldn't delete message hash")
    

def delete_message(self, id):
    if len(id) == 0:
        raise IOError("Hash not found, however database indicates it was uploaded")
    d = self.imap_connection.setFlags(id[-1], ["\\Deleted"])
    d.addCallback(lambda result: self.imap_connection.expunge())
    return d
```

Comment: Since you know of an open-source program that works, start by checking out their code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to SELECT your INBOX not EXAMINE it. Examine is the command to open a mailbox readonly.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb guess my brain saw the examine line and was just like yep you already know it is select yep..... Thanks